# While loop ignoring variables outside of the loop which results in undefined error when clearly defined

Tags: python

I'm making a number guessing game on Python for a school project and have come upon two problems that I cannot find a solution to. I have two questions but decided to post as one question in order to not spam stack overflow.

1. How do I add a while true loop inside a while loop?

I found a neat trick where you can ask the game to keep asking for a number instead of ending the whole code when someone accidentally inserts a letter.

```
while True:
  try:
    guess = int(input("Guess which number I am thinking of: "))
  except ValueError:
    guess = print("That's not a number, guess a NUMBER!")
    continue
  else:
    break
```

My game allows the player to guess six times before failing the game. I do this with a while loop so I how do I add the above while true loop into the while loop that I already have:

```
while GuessesTaken < 6:

  GuessesTaken = GuessesTaken + 1;
  GuessesLeft = 6 - GuessesTaken;

  guess = input("Guess which number I am thinking of: ")
  guess = int(guess)

  if guess < hidden and GuessesLeft==0:
    GuessesLeft=str(GuessesLeft)
    print("Your guess is too low, you have " + GuessesLeft + " guesses left")
    break

  elif guess < hidden and GuessesLeft > 0:
    GuessesLeft=str(GuessesLeft)
    print("Your guess is too low, you have " + GuessesLeft + " guesses left")

  elif guess > hidden and GuessesLeft==0:
    GuessesLeft=str(GuessesLeft)
    print("Your guess is too low, you have " + GuessesLeft + " guesses left")
    break

  elif guess > hidden and GuessesLeft > 0:
    GuessesLeft=str(GuessesLeft)
    print("Your guess is too low, you have " + GuessesLeft + " guesses left")

  elif guess==hidden:
    break
```

2. When variables are defined outside of loop but used within loop, it says the variable is not defined.

I have no idea how to fix the first problem but I have tried a lot of things in an attempt to solve the second problem.

```
def main():
  hidden = random.randint(1,100)  

while GuessesTaken < 6:

  GuessesTaken = GuessesTaken + 1;
  GuessesLeft = 6 - GuessesTaken;

  guess = input("Guess which number I am thinking of: ")
  guess = int(guess)

  if guess < hidden and GuessesLeft==0:
    GuessesLeft=str(GuessesLeft)
    print("Your guess is too low, you have " + GuessesLeft + " guesses left")
    break

  elif guess < hidden and GuessesLeft > 0:
    GuessesLeft=str(GuessesLeft)
    print("Your guess is too low, you have " + GuessesLeft + " guesses left")

  elif guess > hidden and GuessesLeft==0:
    GuessesLeft=str(GuessesLeft)
    print("Your guess is too low, you have " + GuessesLeft + " guesses left")
    break

  elif guess > hidden and GuessesLeft > 0:
    GuessesLeft=str(GuessesLeft)
    print("Your guess is too low, you have " + GuessesLeft + " guesses left")

  elif guess==hidden:
    break
```

This code comes out with a

```
NameError: name 'hidden' is not defined
```

But if I add a

```
hidden = random.randint(1,100)
```

at the top underneath this part of the code

```
score = 0
GuessesTaken = 0
currenttime = str(datetime.now())
currenttime = (
currenttime[0:19])
yesList =("yes", "sure", "yeah", "ye", "yea", "y", "fine", "okay", "ok", "yep")
```

it works until I get to this point of the game

```
if guess!=hidden:
  hidden=str(hidden)
  print("Fail! The number I was thinking of was " + hidden)
  restart=input("Would you like to play again?").lower()
  if restart in yesList:
    main()
```

and the code stops working.

The last thing I tried was adding the while true loop into def main(): like this

```
def main():
  hidden = random.randint(1,100)

  while GuessesTaken < 6:

    GuessesTaken = GuessesTaken + 1;
    GuessesLeft = 6 - GuessesTaken;

    guess = input("Guess which number I am thinking of: ")
    guess = int(guess)

    if guess < hidden and GuessesLeft==0:
      GuessesLeft=str(GuessesLeft)
      print("Your guess is too low, you have " + GuessesLeft + " guesses left")
      break

    elif guess < hidden and GuessesLeft > 0:
      GuessesLeft=str(GuessesLeft)
      print("Your guess is too low, you have " + GuessesLeft + " guesses left")

    elif guess > hidden and GuessesLeft==0:
      GuessesLeft=str(GuessesLeft)
      print("Your guess is too low, you have " + GuessesLeft + " guesses left")
      break

    elif guess > hidden and GuessesLeft > 0:
      GuessesLeft=str(GuessesLeft)
      print("Your guess is too low, you have " + GuessesLeft + " guesses left")

    elif guess==hidden:
      break
```

This came out with a different error message.

```
NameError: name 'guess' is not defined
```

Comment: Check your indentation, both in this post and in your code, there are some strange indetations that may have ocurred when you posted or may be in your code.

Comment: Could you tell me whereabouts the indentation has messed up? I do not seem to see anything abnormal about it at all.

Comment: I'll edit your post and yopu can check the change log

Comment: I used a 2-space indent as it seemed to be what you were using at the start but then you start mixing it with a 4-space indent. Make a decission and stay with it. I personally recommend 4-space indentation.

Comment: I understand now, thank you so much!

Comment: The `NameError` for `hidden` has nothing to do with the loop, but the functions. Each function call holds its own name space (local variables), so `hidden` only existed within `main`. As for putting loops inside other loops, just indent them to match the inside of the loop. The "stops working" I don't quite have the context for; is that `main` call intentional recursion?

Comment: How do I make it so that that `hidden` also exists within the loop without actually putting into the loop. I have tried `global hidden` but that did not seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Constants are spelled `LIKE_THIS`, variables and functions `like_this` and classes `LikeThis`.
2. The number of guesses taken has to be initialized for each game.
3. `var += 1` is the same than `var = var + 1`
4. Using literals (such as the `6` you were using) several times in the code is a good sign that it should be moved to a constant. It also allows you to change this pretty fast.
5. You are already breaking the loop, so checking again if the remaining guesses is 0 will just slow your code.
6. You are doing the same thing in several places when they can be done only once.

The code would be something like:

```
import random

YES_LIST = ("yes", "sure", "yeah", "ye", "yea", "y", "fine", "okay", "ok", "yep")
MAX_GUESSES = 6  # WIN RATES: 1 ->  1% ; 2 ->  3% ; 3 ->  7%
                 #            4 -> 15% ; 5 -> 31% ; 6 -> 63%

def guess_game():
    hidden = random.randint(1, 100)
    guesses_taken = 0
    while guesses_taken < MAX_GUESSES:

        guess = int(input("Guess which number I am thinking of: "))
        guesses_taken += 1
        guesses_left = MAX_GUESSES - guesses_taken

        if guess == hidden:
            break

        if guess < hidden:
            print("Your guess is too low, you have {} guesses left.".format(guesses_left))
        else:
            print("Your guess is too high, you have {} guesses left.".format(guesses_left))

    else:
        # An else of a while loop will only be executed if we do NOT break from it,
        # this is, this part will only be executed if it did not find out the answer
        return False, hidden  # We return False meaning it failed and the hidden number

    # As we returned already if he didn't guess, this will only be executed if he did guess
    return True, hidden  # We return True meaning it succeeded and the hidden number

def main():
    restart = True
    score = 0
    games = 0
    while restart:
        success, number = guess_game()
        games += 1
        if success:
            score += 1
            print("Congrats, you guessed my number.")
        else:
            print("Fail! The number I was thinking of was {}.".format(number))
        restart = input("Want to play again?").lower() in YES_LIST
    print("Thank you! You guesses {} out of {} numbers.".format(score, games))

main()
```

I added some code to allow the user to replay as you were showing hints that you were doing that yourself too.

Comment: I copied and pasted this code to see if it would work and it didn't. I then proceeded to make my own version of this code and that also did not work. The main problem I am having is that in my code I have a `guess=int(input("Guess the number")) within the loop but the code is not recognising the variable `guess`

Comment: There was a typo, has been corrected, it used to say `game +=1` when it should be `games += 1`. You would need to call the function main() at the end.

Comment: Also, what does adding `hidden` into `def guess_game(hidden):` do?

Comment: I'm passing the number that must be guessed to the function, instead of generating it inside. You can generate it inside if you wish.

Comment: Even now, when I run your code it does not work. It stays blank.

Comment: Did you add the `main()` at the end?

Comment: Now it works, still some problem though. If I get the last guess wrong another error pops up. `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'game' referenced before assignment`

Comment: Thats the error I already told you about. inside `main` change `game += 1` for `games += 1`. It was a typo.

Comment: If I was to make the game ask for my name, where would I add it? Would I add it at the very top before defining guess_game?

Comment: `"a string with {}".format(var)` would replace "{}" by the value of `var`. If you were to ask for the name, I would do at the start of `main`.

Comment: I implemented some of your ideas into mine but I don't want the score to restart each time you play again so I put `score=0` at the very top underneath `MAX_GUESSES`. This comes out with an `UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment`. So I added `global score` but that also does not work. How do I fix this?

Comment: My score has persistency. If you play 7 games it will store how many games have played and how many you have guessed the number. Once the user says he doesn't want to continue playing the process will stop so there is NO way to keep the score just using the script. If you want to persist between script executions you will have to store it outside the script. This can be done in a file. If the script finds the file it will start with that score, if he can not find the file it will start at 0.

Comment: The problem is when to store the new score in the file. If you wait until a user says that he doesn't want to play more to update the score in the file, you will have problems if a user closes the window with the cross instead of saying no. So I would recommend to update the file every time a number is guessed or failed.